# Appium - Found existing chromedriver for context ; Using it

Tags: appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate a hybrid app in which I am constantly switching between Web and Native view.

The functions I am using are

```
public void switchToWebContext() throws InterruptedException {
    Set<String> contextNames = appiumDriver.getContextHandles();
    for (String context : contextNames) {
        System.out.println("Context is" + context);
        if (context.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
            getAppiumWebDriver().context(context);
            displayLog("Mobile Web View switched");
        }
    }
}

public void switchToNativeContext() {
    Set<String> contextNames = getAppiumWebDriver().getContextHandles();
    for (String context : contextNames) {
        if (context.contains("NATIVE")) {
            displayLog("Native View found");
            getAppiumWebDriver().context(context);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem here is that for the first time the navigation takes flow properly but on the second turn I get this error

```
Found existing chromedriver for context
```

After I wait for few minutes the error I get is

```
    [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /url] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/ad84071a45fc33c30541cc85681dab7b/url] with no body
[debug] [AndroidDriver] ChromeDriver is not associated with a window. Re-initializing the session.
[Chromedriver] Restarting chromedriver
[debug] [Chromedriver] Changed state to 'restarting'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/ad84071a45fc33c30541cc85681dab7b] with no body
```

Can someone help me out on this? Is there any way in which I can use the existing context or store it in some manner for future use

I amusing Appium 1.6.5 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to switch between WEB_VEIW and  NATIVE. The latest uiAutomator has the inbuilt support for both the views. Just update the "Android System WebView" of the device from PlayStore and update your Android SDK. You code should run without switching between the VIEWs.